# Basic styling in an html page with CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to preface this by saying that this website comes highly recommended and was recommended by my professor to help "learn on our own."  My question is probably incredibly simple and I apologize if it seems as a "waste of space".  I am doing an assignment that requires creating a submittable proper functioning form in vim using HTML and CSS for styling on the course's server.

I have it all laid out as is, however, I have multiple labels in the body ("First Name"/"Last Name" "Class year selection box"/ "address"/"City"/ and "email".  The First Name, Last Name, and Email are all what I am trying to style as "red text" to denote that these are the required fields.

I have the [code s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLcZ5.png)et up to where these are required in order to submit the form, but I cannot figure out how to style it in the header to where I can differentiate which labels need to be in "red".  As it is now, when I insert " Label { color:red; } in the header, it turns all of the text into red. Is there a way to denote specific labels to be red and the non-required labels to remain in black text color? I have tried to insert numbers into the label inputs to denote the different labels in need of a red text color but it applies it to all of the text on the form.

Is there anyway to properly add an identifying feature into a label to allow only the chosen labels as being red?

I appreciate any feedback and I apologize again if this is a waste of time for seasoned coders/developers to have to answer this question. Any input is appreciated.

[How my form looks now online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLcZ5.png)

[The header (that has it all red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkQLu.png)

[The  (this is where I am lost with inserting class properly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4T1a.png)

Comment: To clarify, the course server is a GitHub server ran by the professor.  Not sure if that is relevant, I am just super new to all of this and eager to figure this out on my own and all my lurking on this site and similar sites have left me confused and unsure if the feedback on other posts is exactly what I was looking for.  Not sure if the professor will allow us to use plug-ins or vscode, as I think he is trying to have us learn the basics with regular vim.

Comment: Can you post your code please?  Edit your question and use the "code snippet" button.

Comment: This question isn't a great fit for StackOverflow as it is a little too fundamental in nature. That being said a good place for you to start is : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors , specifically look at CSS classes

Comment: To encourage some more "learning on your own" you have the requirement " denote specific labels to be red  [as they are fore required fields]" . You have a `class` of labels that are associated with a *required*  field and you wish to style those labels. Add a `required` calss to the label then style appropriately. The link in my comment above will help lead you down that path.

Comment: Thank you.  I think that is exactly what I should have been doing.  Thank you for the link.

Comment: @ Seth B.  I think I will try to code snippet a portion of my code to help illustrate what I am dealing with.  I am just a little confused on how to do this.  Is it just clicking edit and pasting the code, or a screen shot of my vim terminal?  Sorry for my stupidity, total learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

At your HTML file add a class to each label you want to target individually, e.g.

```
<span class="label firstName">Joe</span>
```

At your CSS target this class and format the way you want, e.g.

```
.firstName {color: #f44336;}
```

This will target your label with the class of firstName and color the text RED.

Comment: Thank you.  Let me try this real quick. I apologize that I didn't not post a screen shot of the code, but I think that the "class" target is what I am doing wrong.  Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to approach this. If you are allowed to use only HTML and CSS, you can try to create multiple div's in the HTML file and create a CSS property in the CSS file that "styles" the required fields.

**HTML**

```
<div class="forms-box">
      <h2>My Forms</h2>
      <form>
        <div class="user-box">
          <input type="text" name="" required="" />
          <label>First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
          <input type="password" name="" required="" />
          <label>Last Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
          <input type="password" name="" required="" />
          <label>Last Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box3">
          <label>Class year</label>
          <select type="checked" required="" name="class-year">
            <option value="2021">2021</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
          <input type="password" name="" required="" />
          <label>Address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
          <input type="password" name="" required="" />
          <label>City</label>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
          <input type="password" name="" required="" />
          <label>Email</label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(#141e30, #243b55);
}

.forms-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.forms-box h2 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.forms-box .user-box {
  position: relative;
}

.forms-box .user-box input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.forms-box .user-box label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.forms-box .user-box3 label {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.forms-box .user-box3 select {
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.forms-box .user-box input:focus ~ label,
.forms-box .user-box input:valid ~ label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

I have created a mock up which lists all the required fields that need to be filled before submitting.

Here is the link to my [mockup](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-i4ikk?file=/index.html)